# Use sql to select data, then insert row in first position of result set only (not update database)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I select a column in a table, say 10 rows, can I use SQL to insert a 'please select' row into the first position using SQL only? I want to insert it in the result set only - not the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First you should know this is a bad idea**.

You are confusing your presentation layer and your database layer.  Forcing SQL to do things like output status messages or feedback to users is an antipattern to be avoided.

That being said, if the column is of a string type (`char`, `varchar`, etc), you can do something like:

```
SELECT 'Please Select'
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 10 Varcharfield
FROM Mytable
```

If it's numeric then no unless you cast it to a string type.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  If the SQL is intended to populate a SELECT box on a Web page, I think it would be better to add the "Please Select" option in code on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can try:

```
SELECT u.YourVarcharColumnName
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS rID, 'Please select' AS YourVarcharColumnName
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS rID, YourVarcharColumnName
    FROM YourTableName
) u
ORDER BY u.rID;
```

I placed `rID` in place and sorted by it as an extreme-case-measure when your intended first rowset does not come out on top...

However, you should keep in mind that `YourVarcharColumnName` should be (as it says) a string. You'll have to convert it to a string if it's a non-string column.

As @JNK mentioned it.. I thought I should edit my post as well:

Please first try:

```
    SELECT 'Please select' AS YourVarcharColumnName
    UNION
    SELECT YourVarcharColumnName
    FROM YourTableName
```

Which is similar to what the others have posted. If you ever experience what I've been unfortunate to encounter and 'Please select' doesn't come out on top, please refer to the query I posted at the top.. Thanks!

Comment: What value does the `rID` add here?

Comment: What it does is ensure that `Please select` comes out at the very top.. Sorry.. just added it because I've had 2 or 3 experiences where.. weirdly.. the first query in the union doesn't end on top.. is it overkill?

Comment: Never had an issue with that so I was just curious.

Comment: @JNK - edited my post.. in case using `rID` would be unnecessary for others.. thanks!

Comment: @Nonym - when your first query did not come out on top, do you remember if you used "UNION" or "UNION ALL" ?

Comment: @MoeSisko - I used just `union` because the data I worked with before had duplicates.. Any chance that you might have known someone who experienced something similar?

Comment: @Nonym - no, I was just curious. Perhaps its more likely to occur when just "union" is used, since SQLServer needs to do some work to eliminate duplicates. Although nothing in the specs seem to guarantee that it won't ever happen with "union all". So your explicit ordering approach seems safest.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '(Please select)'
UNION
SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName
```

Comment: Sure, or just use CAST(ColumnName AS VARCHAR). Ugly gets uglier.